Solving the recurrence $F(n+1, m+1) = (1/2) F(n, m+2) + (1/2) F(n+2, m) + 1$ with $F(0, m) = F(n, 0) = 0$
Consider the recurrence, defined for integers $n, m \geq 0$ by
$$
F(n+1, m+1) = (1/2) F(n, m+2) + (1/2) F(n+2, m) + 1
$$
with $F(0, m)= F(n, 0) =0$.
I can see that $F(n, m) = nm$ "works" in the sense that it satisfies the boundary conditions and
$$
(n+1)(m+1) = 1 + n + m + nm = (1/2) n(m+2) + (1/2) m(n+2) + 1,
$$
as needed.
However is there a more ``direct'' way to find the explicit form? I tried to use generating functions, but this gets quite complicated.

That isn't the only solution. You can partition your domain into sets with the same $m+n$ and solve the relation for each of them and combine to make a full solution. This means you only need to solve a simple 1 dimensional recurrence relation.

Hm, I am not sure I follow this. Could you expand more on that?

Your recurrence relation only relates points that have the same value of $m+n$, so you can just solve it for each of those partition sets, and combining them back together the relation will still hold, because the relation doesn't require them to fit in with each other in any way. Then on each partition set you can just look at it as a one-variable recurrence relation in $m$, because $m$ determines $n$.

I believe this is actually wrong: there seems to be a unique solution based on this recurrence. See my solution below, and let me know if you disagree.

Sorry, I forgot about the initial conditions. taking them into account there is only one solution.

Define $G_m(k) = F(k, m-k)$. Then it is easy to see that
$$
G_m(k+1) = 2G_m(k) - G_m(k-1) - 2
$$
with initial conditions $G_m(0) = 0$ and $G_m(1) = g$, which is unknown so far.
Solving this recurrence by hand, we see that
$$
G_m(k) = k (g-k + 1), \quad \mbox{for}~k\geq 0.
$$
In other words, we find that
$$
F(m, n) = m \Big(F(1, n + m - 1) - m + 1\Big).
$$
However, now note that for $m > 0$ we have
$$
0 = F(m, 0) = m \Big(F(1, m -1) - (m-1)\Big).
$$
Hence we have $F(1, m) = m$ for all $m \geq 1$. Consequently, for $n, m \geq 1$, we have
$$
F(m, n) = mn.
$$
Combining with the boundary conditions yields
$$
F(m, n) = mn \quad \mbox{for all}~m, n \geq 0.
$$
